# Event-driven linux process monitor: how to do that?

Tags: c, linux

I have a unstable program that kept crashing randomly, I could use a bash script to keep it running, but is there a way to monitor it's state ? Not by polling, but event-driven.

And and optional question, what if the monitor process isn't the parent process of it, is this still possible ?

Comment: When you have crashing programs, always run it in a debugger! However, if it seems to be randomly then I suggest using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to check for problems with memory allocations/access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple wrapper which forks and execs the crashing process, and just wakes up when it gets SIGCHLD and starts all over again; *conceptual* code below:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t gotchld = 0;

void
sigchld_handler(int sig)
{
    if (sig == SIGCHLD)
        gotchld = 1;
}

signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_handler);

for (;;) {
    switch ((pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
        err(1, "fork");
    case 0:
        exec_my_crashy_program_here();
        errx(1, "came back from exec!");    /* paranoia */
    default:
        printf("sleeping for pid %u\n", pid);
        while (!gotchld)
            select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);  /* sleep forever waiting for signal */
        /* possibly do fancy stuff with the wait() family of functions */
        gotchild = 0;
        continue;    
    }
}
```

You don't need anything fancy, just a basic knowledge of how child and parent processes interact via signals.

Please also consider that it's been a while since I've dealt with signal stuff directly, so double-check that the code there is correct.

Comment: fork() + waitpid() solved my problem actually, thanks for the heads up

Comment: yeah, waitpid() is a better solution in this case; I've apparently been away from a full unix userland for too long

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's still possible. If you want to write your own application to do this you have to use `ptrace`. It allows you to attach to the process as a debugger and wait for certain events. I described using `ptrace` on my blog. Here you can read more about that with some examples: http://purecode.pl/blog/?tag=ptrace

Comment: Your blog entry doesn't really show how to use `ptrace` to detect that a process ends. is `PTHREAD_ATTACH` followed by `wait(NULL)`  enough?

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your question whether you are trying to ensure that the program keeps running, or whether you are trying to debug it.

If you are trying to keep it running, try Monit: http://mmonit.com/monit/

Answer (score 0):

You could try inotify or a similar service and watch for /proc/PID to be deleted?

Comment: This is, depending on whether the inotify daemon checks for /proc/$pid again, racy, as are essentially all ops requiring use of /proc.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the process with a bash script, that *does* monitor its state: execution of the script resumes after the process exits, and gets the exit code.  That's event-driven.

As for monitoring a non-child process, Yob and user1442158 have already made reasonable suggestions.